# Can't resolve dependency of Enyim.Caching

Tags: c#, couchbase, enyim, enyim.caching

I have a problem with resolving dependency to Enyim.Caching.dll while using Couchbase client. I have downloaded the dlls via NuGet and referenced them in the project. The solution compiles fine with the downloaded assembly Enyim.Caching, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**05e9c6b5a9ec94c2**. But in the runtime Couchbase throws an exception because it is looking for Enyim.Caching, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**cec98615db04012e**.

I can't undestand why it requires another dll of the same version, but with another PublicKey.

I also tried the solution described in [Cant get the couchbase .net memcache client to run, complains it's strong name validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977053/cant-get-the-couchbase-net-memcache-client-to-run-complains-its-strong-name-v) to remove strongname requirements via using ns.exe. But it didn't workout.

Can anoyone help me?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?  You shouldn't need to worry about strong name validation as Nuget builds are all signed.  Also, which version on Nuget are you using?

Comment: Sadly, I have deleted all log files with the stacktrace before reading  your answer :( But I have managed to solve the problem via solution described below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to solve this problem using description in the file Readme.mdown of couchbase-net-client project. They say that there are 2 ways to solve the problem: either remove the strong name checking via sn.exe or via removing assembly signing at all.

I have chosen the second way, since I don't that need assembly signing. I rebuilt the source from the scratch, removed every entry NuGet has created for me and manually added references to all assemblies. And it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

you can delete node with "public_key.snk" in file "build/CommonProperties.targets"

```
<!-- delay sign the assembly if the PrivateKeyPath property is not specified -->
<!--<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(PrivateKeyPath)' == '' And '$(PrivateKeyName)' == ''">
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\public_key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <DelaySign>true</DelaySign>
</PropertyGroup> -->
```