# Couchbase not working on production server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, couchbase, strongname, strong-named-key

I am using Couchbase client inside my asp.net web mvc project (i downloaded the dll files from [here](http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/current))

I have a Couchbase Server installed on Windows Server 2012 x64.

When developing the project, everything works as expected. When i publish the website on the server, i get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Enyim.Caching' or one of its dependencies.

Strong name signature could not be verified. 

The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
```

I am stuck! i have also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977053/cant-get-the-couchbase-net-memcache-client-to-run-complains-its-strong-name-v/8977433#8977433), but with no effect.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the 1.2.2 build (signing related).  There's a fix posted to http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/net/1.2/Couchbase-Net-Client-1.2.3.zip (NuGet is also updated).  I'll investigate as to why the site doesn't have the new links.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you..i got the packages from nuget and it is working. The link you posted returns Access Denied

Comment: Sorry - the access denied issue should be fixed now.